# DLL failed importing SSL

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I've got this lengthy error from SSL:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bala006\OneDrive - St John's Anglican College\Desktop\Personal\Pro Torch\Cats vs Dogs\osm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\geopy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\__init__.py", line 221, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders.algolia import AlgoliaPlaces
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\algolia.py", line 5, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders.base import DEFAULT_SENTINEL, Geocoder
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from geopy.adapters import (
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\geopy\adapters.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ssl import SSLError
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl: The specified module could not be found
```

Every single fix provided online is useless. I've successfully installed it using conda(I use miniconda) but when I try using pip I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations\_sysconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import InvalidSchemeCombination, UserInstallationInvalid
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (C:\Users\bala006\Miniconda3.8\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py)
```

What should I do?

Comment: *"Every single fix provided online is useless"* - This statement is wrong. The truth is that every single fix _you were able to find_ did not work _when you tried it_. This might be due to problems with the specific fix itself, an inability of you to properly apply the fix or an inability of you to find the right fix. Unfortunately basically the only information found here is "does not work", which isn't that useful to help with your problem.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] first. Then, include that along with the expected and actual output here. First though, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: See also [this issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11994) which describes a possible solution: *"...  If I copy needed DLLs to a directory that Python is actually looking in, such as [Anaconda base directory]\DLLs, the error goes away"*. No idea if you've tried this already.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm pretty new to this thing. I've tried the moving of DLL's (which was found when I asked on another forum) and still got the messy second error when installing from pip. Is my pip system broken because that's what I get from everything that I pip install...